# How do I process a CSV file in scala so that I can separate its lines into arrays?

Tags: scala, csv

I am trying to process a 300+ line long csv file in scala into an array.

The csv file contains looks like this

```
20200522T0600,26.852346
20200522T0700,26.862345
20200522T0800,27.262346
20200522T0900,28.562346
20200522T1000,29.472345
20200522T1100,29.432346
```

These are the date, time and temperature. I have to put (datetime) and (temperature) into separate parallel arrays, I'm supposed to calculate the average temperatures later on but I can do that. I just don't know how to read them into those 2 arrays. I know I have to use fromFile() and .getLines to obtain the lines but I'm stuck with the array part.

I tried this

```
object Weather {

    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val source = Source.fromFile("Weather.csv")
        var matrix :Array[String] = Array.empty
        for(line <- source.getLines.drop(10)){
            val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toArray
            matrix = :+ cols
            println(matrix)
        }

    }
}
```

but I get this result

```
[error]             matrix = :+ cols
[error]                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 9, 2020 6:26:56 AM
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at my answer on very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737552/how-to-add-data-in-csv-file-using-scala it should helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `split()` returns an array so `.toArray` isn't needed. And `= :+` isn't Scala so that's not going to get you very far.

Try this.

```
val lines = io.Source
              .fromFile("Weather.csv")  //open file
              .getLines                 //Iterator[String]
              .drop(10)                 // ?
              .map(_.split(","))        //Iterator[Array[String]]
```

Add a `.toList` at the end if you need to load everything into memory.

To see the result.

```
lines.foreach(println)
```

Or you might have to do something like this.

```
lines.foreach(arr => println(arr.mkString("Array(", ",", ")")))
```